# Windows WlanApi and Python Ctypes

Tags: python, windows, wifi, ctypes

I'm working on a captive portal projet on Windows. I've written this piece of code (similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) :

```
from ctypes import wintypes
import ctypes

WlanApi = ctypes.windll.wlanapi

hClientHandle = wintypes.HANDLE()
phClientHandle = ctypes.pointer(hClientHandle)
dwNegotiatedVersion = wintypes.DWORD()
pdwNegotiatedVersion = ctypes.pointer(dwNegotiatedVersion)
dwClientVersion = wintypes.DWORD()
dwClientVersion.value = 2L

rc = WlanApi.WlanOpenHandle(dwClientVersion, None, pdwNegotiatedVersion, phClientHandle)
print rc

class GUID(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Data1", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("Data2", wintypes.WORD),
                ("Data3", wintypes.WORD),
                ("Data4", wintypes.BYTE * 8)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO (ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('InterfaceGuid', GUID),
                ('strInterfaceDescription', wintypes.WCHAR * 256),
                ('isState', wintypes.????)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwNumberOfItems', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwIndex', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('InterfaceInfo', WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO * 10)]

IfList = WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST()
pIfList = ctypes.pointer(IfList)
rc = WlanApi.WlanEnumInterfaces(hClientHandle, None, pIfList)

print rc
print "Num Entries: %s" % IfList.dwNumberOfItems
```

I can't find how to structure "[WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)" and when I try with a `WCHAR` array or anything else, this script return my 6000000 wireless interfaces !!!

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If I replace dwNumberOfItems by a Byte Array, my script return this : \nNum Entries: -32 76 80 00 00 00 00 00\nOn a second run I get\nNum Entries: -32 76 60 00 00 00 00 00\n\nMaybe the problem is in the HANDLE pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an integer, there is no structure 0 = Not ready, 1 = connected etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it starts to make sense,as most of these structs have a  corresponding pointer.

According to the boys at PInvoke

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
{
  /// GUID->_GUID
  public Guid InterfaceGuid;
  /// WCHAR[256]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
  public string strInterfaceDescription;
  /// WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE->_WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE
  public WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE isState;
}
```

Where WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE is

```
public enum WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE
{
  wlan_interface_state_not_ready = 0,
  ...
  // 1 to 6
  ...
  wlan_interface_state_authenticating = 7,
}
```

[PInvoke on WLAN...](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO.html)